# Laravel delete not working with skip and take

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble deleting the relation model records, I want to keep some records and delete all others, for example, there is x number of records in the table now I want to keep the first five and delete all others.
I am using skip and take to filter the records.

```
$quiz->questions()->latest()->skip($request->total_questions)->take(PHP_INT_MAX)->each(function ($row) {
    $row->options()->delete();
    $row->delete();
});
```

I have a model quiz that has related questions and questions have other relation options so what I won't do is keep some questions like 5 or 6 maybe and delete all other questions with their options but in this query, all questions related to the quiz are deleted.

P.s when I use to get() it shows me the correct result which I want but I don't know why it is not working with delete()!

Please help anyone.

Comment: What kind of relation? If it's many-to-many, is there any model related to pivot table? Do you want to keep the first 5 records of the whole table or the records that related to a specific item?

Comment: should be "P.S" not "P.s"

Comment: One to many relation like quiz has many question and a question has many options, no there is not any pivot table related. not specifically first 5 it can be 5, 10 or any number, thank u for your reply @BülentAkgül. Abdullah shakir reply worked for me

Comment: Will be careful next time @JinghuiNiu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `get()` after `take()` as following:

```
$quiz->questions()->latest()->skip($request->total_questions)->take(PHP_INT_MAX)->get()->each(function ($row) {
    $row->options()->delete();
    $row->delete();
});
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I was missing get() method, it is working now @AbdullahShakir